# Flutter PositionedTransitioned to below other Stack child - how to get height?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm doing a backdrop style slide down similar to the [Codelabs flutter example here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-104-flutter). I'd like the foreground part to stop at the bottom of the backdrop content.

I know you can't get the height directly until after layout. Since the app starts with the foreground part at the top, I was thinking I could get the height after build and store it in the state, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this.

This is what I have now, just using a predefined 'overhang' that doesn't account for the backdrop content height:

```
Widget _buildForeground(BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    Animation<RelativeRect> rectAnimation = new RelativeRectTween(
      begin: new RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0.0, constraints.maxHeight - widget.overhang, 0.0, 0.0),
      end: new RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    ).animate(_controller);
    return new PositionedTransition(
      rect: rectAnimation,
      child: new Material(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(topLeft: new Radius.circular(15.0), topRight: new Radius.circular(15.0))),
        elevation: 16.0,
        child: widget.foreground,
      )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,),
          widget.background,
          _buildForeground(context, constraints),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Need more details. Why can't you get the height when starting the animation ?

Comment: The only way I know to get the hight would be `context.size.height`, and if I put that here then I get an error because you can't get the height before layout has occurred. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Oh sorry, I see what you mean. I start the animation by listening to a stream event in this widget, so I have the buildcontext of the whole thing. How would I go from there to the height of widget.background?

Comment: You're not gonna get the size of `widget.background`. But `Material` wrapping it. take a look at [`GlobalKey`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html)

Comment: Genius, I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Remi I came up with this solution using GlobalKey

```
void _toggleForeground() {
  setState(() => top = backgroundKey?.currentContext?.size?.height);
  _controller.fling(velocity: _isBackgroundVisible ? -widget.toggleVelocity : widget.toggleVelocity);
}

Widget _buildForeground() {
  if (top == null) top = 500.0;
  Animation<RelativeRect> rectAnimation = new RelativeRectTween(
    begin: new RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0.0, top, 0.0, 0.0),
    end: new RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
  ).animate(_controller);
  return new PositionedTransition(
    rect: rectAnimation,
    child: new Material(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(topLeft: new Radius.circular(15.0), topRight: new Radius.circular(15.0))),
      elevation: 16.0,
      child: widget.foreground,
    )
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        new Column(
          key: backgroundKey,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[widget.background],
        ),
        _buildForeground(),
    ],
  );
}
```